# Why $ \Vert A \Vert \leq \frac{1}{2} ( \Vert A + A^* \Vert + \Vert A - A^* \Vert )?$

Tags: operator-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

> If $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, why we have
>   $$ \Vert A \Vert
> \leq \frac{1}{2} ( \Vert A + A^* \Vert + \Vert A - A^* \Vert )?$$

Comment: Is $A^\star$ the conjugate transpose? I think its more standard to use $A^*$, `A^*`.

Comment: $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$.

Comment: Sorry yes I was somehow forgetting that word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the equality
$$ A = \frac12 (A + A^*) + \frac12 (A-A^*).$$